# How to display file into binary format with php?

Tags: php, binary

To create a new file ,to input just one enter key and save it as test.txt.
There is only one '\n' in the test.txt.
To display the file with command:

```
 xxd  -b ./test.txt
 0000000: 00001010
```

Now i want to do the same job with php.

```
<?php
function  parse($target){
    $file_handle = fopen($target, "rb");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $byte = fread($file_handle,1);
       echo  base_convert(ord($byte),10,2);
    }   
    fclose($file_handle );
} 
parse('test.txt');  
?>
```

The result is 10100 ,how to fix my php code to get the such right answer 00001010  as  xxd  -b ./test.txt  ?
Think to Pyton's code.

```
<?php
function  parse($target){
    $file_handle = fopen($target, "rb");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $byte = fread($file_handle,1);
       echo  sprintf("%08s ",base_convert(ord($byte), 10, 2));
    }   
    fclose($file_handle );
} 
$target='test.txt';  
echo filesize($target);
parse($target);
?>
```

The filesize is 1,but result is  `00001010 00000000` ,how to make it to be exactly  `00001010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function  parse($target){
    $file_handle = fopen($target, "rb");
    $filesize = filesize($target);    
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $byte = fread($file_handle, 1);
        echo sprintf("%'08b", ord($byte));
        if(ftell($file_handle) == $filesize) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle );
}
parse('test.txt');
```

Output:

```
00001010
```

Comment: The filesize is 1,but result is 00001010 00000000 ,how to make it to be exactly 00001010?